# How to recompile just a single kernel module?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kernel-module

Usually kernel source are stored in `/usr/src/linux-2.6.x/`.
To avoid to recompile the entire kernel if I modify a module's source, how can I recompile just that module?

Answer (score 63):

Switch to the root directory of your source tree and run the following command:

```
$ make modules SUBDIRS=drivers/the_module_directory
```

And to install the compiled module:

```
$ make modules_install SUBDIRS=drivers/the_module_directory
```

*Note:* As lunakid mentions, the latter command might *not* build the module first, so be careful.

Comment: (Just make sure you run that in the tree root, unlike me. ;) )

Comment: @lunakid Good point ;) Although it should be pretty clear that `SUBDIRS` is relative to the CWD :P

Comment: It's definitely clear, but then I still found myself sitting in the wacom driver dir in the end. :) Just not watched my steps. Also, could you please add to your answer that it can also be **installed** the same way, just putting `make modules_install SUBDIRS=...`. That's almost certainly the next step, and may not be immediately trivial (even though it seems so, after e.g. I spent some minutes googling it in vain... :) ). Thx, cheers!

Comment: @lunakid Done. I assume modules_install also builds, so it's really a one-step process

Comment: +1, thx. As to build+install: seems not: it unfortunately just craps itself, if this is indeed what it feels like: 
  INSTALL drivers/input/touchscreen/wacom_w8001.ko
cp: cannot stat 'drivers/input/touchscreen/wacom_w8001.ko': No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  3.4.34-x61t`
(Still runs DEPMOD, though, that's why I'm unsure.)

Comment: @lunakid Ok thanks for the feedback, I incorporated this into my answer

Comment: Great job, too bad I can't +2 it. :)

Comment: This solution does not work. Trying this with `mmc_block.ko` returns a message that says something like `No rule to make block.o`.

Comment: Once we have done make_install, does it also load the library? I tried rmmod dm_raid (module that I was building), checked if it had successfully been removed, and then again inserted the module. Still I do not see updated printk's I have placed in my new instrumented module. Can you please tell if we need to do other things after make_install so that changes in driver get reflected?

Answer (score 25):

since kernel versions **3.x.x** and **4.x.x** the procedure gets more complicated (but there is a hope, so keep reading):

1. `make distclean` if you haven't just cloned a new source but used to build other modules before
2. create new folder somewhere for the module source (example: **extra**)
   and copy only source files (from the kernel source or somewhere else) related to the module needed to be build into this new folder
3. copy `` /boot/config-`uname -r` `` file (example: **/boot/config-4.8.0-46-generic**) into kernel source folder file **.config** and run `make oldconfig`. if the module belongs to the kernel source, verify if it has been enabled by calling `make menuconfig`, by searching for the module and applying letter 'M' if necessary
4. kernel source root **Makefile** has to be altered with exact version components matching the current running one (you may verify with `make kernelversion` if it matches exactly the `uname -r`one)
5. there is been a strong suggestion to build scripts also before with 
   `make scripts`
6. `make prepare` and `make modules_prepare` has to be executed prior to the actual module build
7. **Module.symvers** has to be copied from the target system headers folder corresponding running kernel version `` /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/Module.symvers `` (example: **/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-117-generic/Module.symvers**) into the newly created module source files folder prepared for the module compilation (the one **extra** in example).
8. create new **Makefile** inside module source compilation folder having following line: `obj-y += <module_source_file_name>.o` or if the source code is complicated, use the guidance from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)
9. only then it's the right time to build module with `make -C <kernel source path> M=the_module_directory` (example: `make -C . M=extra/`)
10. Use command `modprobe --dump-modversion <module_name>.ko` to verify CRC match between module exporting API and corresponding values in **Module.symvers**. in case of failure use command `modinfo <module_name>.ko` instead
11. verify if **kernel.release** file content match exactly the one from headers of the current running version. if you'll discover **+** appended at the end, it means you've been compiling git clonned source and your experimental modifications caused build system to compromise the localversion string by adding **+** at the end.
12. if only **+** has been discovered at the tail of **kernel.release** stored value and it's a mismatch with the exact name of the target running kernel,

the solution would be following:

commit all your changes, force release tag to shift above your modifications with the `git tag -a <tag version> -f` command. then rebuild your modules from step 8

Comment: If the driver has its own subdirectory (e.g. linux/drivers/net/ethernet/natsemi) is it still necessary to copy the driver code into its own "extra" folder?

Comment: FYI for others who may run into `Symbol version dump "vmlinux.symvers" is missing.`: You may need to `cp Module.symvers vmlinux.symvers` in your Linux source tree.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the path to the module name or module directory to make as parameter.

```
make path/to/the/module/itself.ko
make path/to/the/module/directory/
```

Comment: make path/to/the/module/itself.ko takes much more time comparing to the  make modules SUBDIRS=directory/path (3 minuts vs 5 seconds). Actually, just the make path/to/directory doesn't seems to work, it always say "Nothing to be done", but I did modify the code

Answer (score 9):

In case you have edited just code in drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_main.c file

**Build the module.**

```
make scripts prepare modules_prepare
make -C . M=drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000
```

**Install the module.**

```
cp drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000.ko /lib/modules/5.1.15/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000.ko
```

Answer (score 4):

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module