# Rebuild linux kernel module for another architecture

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kernel-module

Suppose I have [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) machine with some version of Linux kernel. And I have directory with kernel sources of another version. The kernel was built for [arm](/questions/tagged/arm) arch and loaded to the appropriate device.
Now I need to rebuild just one kernel module in this big directory.
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module) and tried something like

```
make path/to/the/module/itself.ko
```

, but it build module for amd64.

When I try

```
make M=path/to/the/module/
```

it gives a bunch of arch-related C-errors.

Could someone explain how can easy use this ARM-ready environment to rebuild some kernel module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross compiling a kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467850/cross-compiling-a-kernel-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- M=path/to/the/module/
```

Also read:

[Cross compiling a kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467850/cross-compiling-a-kernel-module)

[gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180185/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-command-not-found)